# OSX 10.7.2 can't shut down

Tags: macos, shutdown

When i click on shutdown nothing happens. I've tried repairing and verifying the hard-disks. Rebooting in safe mode, resetting PRAM, SMC. Nothing seems to work.

The only 2 ways i can shutdown now is by pressing and holding the power button and typing "shutdown -h now" in terminal. Can anyone help me?

Comment: It would be useful if you'd include the kernel log, especially the shutdown related parts.

Comment: I think I've experienced the same thing. A background process gets stuck and prevents the shutdown. For me, it doesn't do this if I log out and then shutdown from the login window.

Comment: If you open Activity Monitor, are there any processes that are red (not responding)?  Be sure to look at All Processes (dropdown at the top right).